# How can i realise median stacking in python?

Tags: python

I'm a student and new to python. Currently I'm trying to code a filter realising median stacking. so i have the following code.

```
image1 = cv.imread('img1.jpg')
image2 = cv.imread('img2.jpg')
image3 = cv.imread('img3.jpg')

median_image = image1.copy()
tgt_size = median_image.size

#Median Stacking
for i in range(tgt_size):
   for j in range(tgt_size):
      median_image[i, j] = [statistics.median([image1[i, j], image2[i, j], image3[i, j]])]
```

It should take three pictures, apply median stacking to them (by changing each pixel individually) and create one final edited image which is saved in median_image. I tried to use statistics.median to get the value for each pixel but when i tried it i got the following error:

```
The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

These are my imports:

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

import statistics
```

Can anybody help me with this task? :)

Comment: Please share a [mre] with full traceback.

Comment: `np.median([image1, image2, image3], axis=0)`

Comment: i changed it to median_image[i, j] = np.median([image1[i, j], image2[i,j], image3[i,j]], axis=0) and now it works

Comment: @LauraB Don't do that! The whole matrix can be calculated directly with the `np.median` function, and the loop calculation is very slow!

Answer (score 2):

I decided to write an answer to remind you that you can complete it with only one statement and avoid using loops. Loops operate on arrays very slowly:

```
image1, image2, image3 = np.random.rand(3, 100, 100)

def loop():
    median_image = np.empty(image1.shape)
    for i in range(median_image.shape[0]):
        for j in range(median_image.shape[1]):
            median_image[i, j] = np.median([image1[i, j], image2[i, j], image3[i, j]])

def vectorize():
    median_image = np.median([image1, image2, image3], axis=0)
```

You will find that vectorization is more than 400 times faster than loop:

```
>>> timeit(loop, number=10)
1.9518220000027213
>>> timeit(vectorize, number=1000)
0.42122590000508353
```